# How to compare against JQuery RGB value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to compare against the returned rgb color value using a simple method in jQuery or Javascript. I've tried everything I can think of, but can't get anything to evaluate true.

```
if( $('.Updated-Alert').css('color') == 'rgb(255,0,0)')
```

I have found other answers that parse through the RGB, but they really seem like major overkill for what I need it for.

Comment: what does `css('color')` return?

Comment: This depends on the browser you're using, firefox 14.0.1 returns 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' while you are comparing 'rgb(255,0,0)' without spaces.

Comment: The string may contain spaces in it (because of the browser). Like `rgb(12, 34, 56)` which would be false for your check.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It just returns a string. Your comparison fails because your white space is preventing the equivalence.

```
$('div').css('color') === 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etLcv/

If you want to harden it a little bit, you could trim whitespace and compare to that:

```
$('div').css('color').replace(/\s+/g, '') === 'rgb(0,0,255)'
```

Or even trim out anything but the digits:

```
$('div').css('color').replace(/\D+/g, '') === '00255'
```

Comment: `rgb(25,50,0)` trim => `25500`; `rgb(255,0,0)` trim => `25500`

Answer (score 4):

Add a space after the values - http://jsfiddle.net/c6874/

```
if ( $("p").css("color") == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' ) {
    alert("It's red");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a simple task in basic javascript, consider the fact that

`white == #FFF == #FFFFFF == rgb(255,255,255) == rgba(255,255,255,0`

Here is a free library that does this:
http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/